Android WebView in Compose Not Displaying Certain Pages Properly
I'm facing an issue with the WebView in my Android Compose application. While the WebView works perfectly on iOS, in the browser, and with Flutter WebView on both Android and iOS, certain websites break and become unresponsive when using the WebView with Compose and Kotlin.
Here's the code I'm using:
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Composable
internal fun WebView(downloadListener: SDKDownloadListener, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    var showSplash by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

    Box(modifier = modifier) {
        AndroidView(
            factory = { context ->
                WebView(context).apply {
                    // Clear various caches and preferences
                    clearCache(true)

                    // Configure WebView settings
                    settings.apply {
                        javaScriptEnabled = true
                        domStorageEnabled = true
                        databaseEnabled = true
                        allowContentAccess = true
                        allowFileAccess = true
                    }

                    // Set WebView properties
                    webViewClient = WebViewClient()
                    webChromeClient = WebChromeClient()

                    // Set download listener
                    setDownloadListener(downloadListener)

                    // Add JavaScript interface
                    addJavascriptInterface(EventListenerJavascriptInterface(), JAVASCRIPT_INTERFACE)

                    // Load URL with POST data
                    postUrl("https://post.dev", body)
                }
            },
            modifier = Modifier.matchParentSize(),
        )

        // Splash screen with animation
        AnimatedVisibility(
            visible = showSplash,
            exit = slideOutVertically(targetOffsetY = { it }) + fadeOut(),
            modifier = Modifier.matchParentSize()
        ) {
            SplashView(onButtonPress = { showSplash = false })
        }
    }
}

Tried:

Clearing cache, setting javascript enabled, enabling database etc.
Checking for any JavaScript errors on the websites.

Despite these efforts, certain websites still break and are unresponsive. Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can provide insights into what might be going wrong? Any help would be appreciated!
Additional Information:
The same websites work fine on iOS and in the browser. Flutter WebView works perfectly on both Android and iOS with the same websites.

yes im having exact same problem atm in a jetpack compose app (a login webpage not displaying correctly, but renders fine in say chrome). would love to know how to solve this too

@ajonno it seems that there's some issue with using WebView on Compose. I ended up porting my code to Kotlin + XML layouts

I solved mine by adding layoutParams. Tried to post this as an answer, but the mod deleted it.
